# Rhinoslider Go back two sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using rhinoslider:

http://rhinoslider.com/api/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-multi-step-form-rhinoslider/

How can I make it go back two slides? For instance, I'm on slide 3, and I want to go back to slide 1. I tried two prev() calls one after another but it doesn't work.

I was thinking of using the callback function to call previous if a global variable is set, or using a timer between the prev() but want to check if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I just limited myself to three slides, and if on slide three called next(), and if on slide two called prev().